# 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

Tags: python

I'm looping through the dictionary itsems, and I'm running into the 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing error when I run the following code:

```
    sent_dict = {}
for i in range(len(tweets)):
    sent_dict[tweets[i]] = sentiments[i]

for k,v in sent_dict.items():
    if v[0][1] < 1 or v[1][1] < 1:
        del sent_dict[k]
```

This code is meant for Python 2.x, and I'm using Python 3.5. I saw the following post, but couldn't translate the solution to the one above: TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please show the sample `sent_dict`

Comment: Also, don't modify your iterable while iterating over it. That leads to bad things.

Comment: When creating `sent_dict`, you’re probably assigning `some_other_dict.keys()` to a key? Convert it to a list instead.

Comment: @Ryan Is right. The problem is not in the code you posted. Somewhere in your for loop your assigning `sent_dict` to the value of some dictionaries keys.

Comment: @JkShaw added the complete code

Comment: @Ryan got it yo